# unable to locate and select an element which is in a table

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried this, but didn't work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[./td[contains(., 'select')]]")).click();
```

below line is clicking the elemnet

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select")).click();`

here is the code

```
<td>
<select class="gwt-ListBox">
<option value="">Select...</option>
```

Comment: You tried one thing and gave up? What else have you tried? What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: Have you tried to use `cssSelector`, instead of `xpath`? Do you have the full HTML code? I think that trying something like `driver.findElement("tr td select").click()` could work (maybe combining some CSS classes you could have).